# How to increase the size of overviewruler items in vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to increase the size (width to be proper) of items shown in the Overview ruler, For example: errors / infos e.t.c

I can customise the color using `"editorOverviewRuler.errorForeground": "#ff0000",` in `"workbench.colorCustomizations": {}`, but how do I increase its size. I've attached a pic to be more clear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the width of the scrollbar, and thus the Overview Ruler markers using the following setting:

```
"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 20,
```

Answer (score 2):

This feature request was not accepted.

Related issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115571

Comment: The feature request was rejected because the solution already exists: verticalScrollbarSize

Comment: ’verticalScrollbarSize‘ does increase the width of overview ruler, but it also increase the width of scrollbar. That's not exactly what I expected.